# Code not lighting every LED in Adafruit Neopixel, using Processing and Arduino

Tags: arduino, processing, neopixel

I'm trying to use Processing to find the average rgb value of my computer screen in sections, and sending that data to Arduino to light my 60 LED strip. The code for changing the colors of the strip to match my computer screen is working, but only for the first 12 LEDs. I cannot figure out what to change to get all 60 LEDs to light up. I've attached the code below, would really appreciate some guidance on this one.

```
//Ambi: AmbientNeoPixel Arduino Sketch
//Created By: Cory Malantonio

#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN 6
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int r[11]; // array for each color value
int g[11];
int b[11];

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 strip.begin(); // prep the neopixel
 strip.show();
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()>=31) {
    if (Serial.read() == 0xff){
      for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++){
        r[x] = Serial.read(); // read in the values from processing
        g[x] = Serial.read(); // in the same order we sent them
        b[x] = Serial.read();

        r[x] = constrain(r[x], 0, 255); // just incase any values slip away
        g[x] = constrain(g[x], 0, 255);
        b[x] = constrain(b[x], 0, 255);

    }
  }
}


int Xval = 0; // count to 30
int Yval = 1; // while loading rgb values
int Zval = 2; // into 3 led's at a time

for (int z = 1; z < 11; z++){

strip.setPixelColor(Xval, r[z], g[z], b[z]);
strip.setPixelColor(Yval, r[z], g[z], b[z]);
strip.setPixelColor(Zval, r[z], g[z], b[z]);

Xval = Xval + 3;
Yval = Yval + 3;
Zval = Zval + 3;
}

strip.show(); //output to the neopixel
delay(20); //for safety
}
```

---

---

Here is the processing sketch,
the only real adjustment you will have to make will be the line
port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[#], 9600;

the # is referring to the usb device number the arduino is plugged into.
i would suggest trying 0, then 1, then 2, etc until you find the one you are using.

---

### --------------------------------Processing Sketch-----------------------------------

### edit: i got a great email asking about changing the resolution on the processing sketch.
Since then, i changed out the processing sketch with one more fit to edit (without having to dive into the code).

```
/*  Ambi2: AmbientNeoPixel Processing Sketch
**  Created by: Cory Malantonio
**  ambiArray is based on a design by Rajarshi Roy
*/


import cc.arduino.*;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import processing.serial.*;


//-------Set Resolution Here-----//
int resX = 1920;
int resY = 1080;
//-------------------------------//

int sectW = resX / 10;  //Section Width for the 10 sections
int SectRx = sectW / 4; //Section resolution for x
int SectRy = resY / 4;  //Section resolution for y

Serial port;
Robot GrabRGBval;

void setup()
{
port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[7], 9600);
//Serial.list()[#], # = usb device number

try
{
GrabRGBval = new Robot();
}
catch (AWTException e)
{
println("Robot class not supported by your system!");
exit();
}

size(200, 200);
background(0);
noFill();
}

void draw()
{
int pixel;

float[] rA = new float[11];
float[] gA = new float[11];
float[] bA = new float[11];
int[] reso = new int[11];

for (int Ar = 1; Ar < 11; Ar++){  //load the resolutions into the array
reso[Ar] = sectW * Ar;              //192 is 1/10th of the 1920 resolution
}

float r=0;
float g=0;
float b=0;
reso[0]=0;

BufferedImage screenshot = GrabRGBval.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(new Dimension(resX, resY)));

for (int LED = 1; LED < 11; LED++){
int x=0;
int y=0;

//reso array increments in 10ths of the 1920 resolution, starting at 0
for ( x = reso[LED-1] ; x < reso[LED]; x = x + 4) {  //"x + 4" is skipping pixels
  for (y = 0; y < resY; y = y + 4) {                 // to help it run faster
    pixel = screenshot.getRGB(x, y);
    r = r+(int)(255&(pixel>>16));
    g = g+(int)(255&(pixel>>8));
    b = b+(int)(255&(pixel));
  }
}

r=r/(SectRx*SectRy); //48 is 1/4th each 10th of the screen. Above we are skipping pixels
g=g/(SectRx*SectRy); //we are left with 1/4th the pixels.
b=b/(SectRx*SectRy); //270 is 1/4th of the 1080 resolution
rA[LED] = r;
gA[LED] = g;
bA[LED] = b;

}

port.write(0xff); //write marker, arduino is looking for this
for (int Br = 1; Br < 11; Br++){
port.write((byte)(rA[Br]));
port.write((byte)(gA[Br]));
port.write((byte)(bA[Br]));
}

delay(10); //delay for safety

for (int cOne = 1; cOne < 11; cOne++){  
fill(0);
stroke(rA[cOne], gA[cOne], bA[cOne]);
rect((cOne - 1)*20, 0, cOne*20, 200);
fill(rA[cOne], gA[cOne], bA[cOne]);
rect((cOne - 1)*20, 0, cOne*20, 200);
}
}
```

Comment: You've got a couple of loops that only go from 1 to 10.  To drive more LEDs, you'd have to increase those limits, and also enlarge your r/g/b arrays to hold all the data.